Please provide a solution to the vertex group selection error issue
When I select only the edges to create a "vertex group", it strangely gets added as a face.
Even if I want to remove unnecessary edges, as you can see in the video, the remaining edges I am trying to group together also get deleted.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve this issue.
++
I am posting a new question because the previous answer did not provide an ultimate solution, and I am using Blender version 4.2.
And I want to add only the edges I selected to the vertex group, not the faces!!!


Additionally, to get expected results when using vertex groups, you should be in vertex selection mode
